# MessageBox shown before form closes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Why is the messagebox shown before the form closes?

```
SomeForm myForm = new SomeForm();
myForm.Show();
MessageBox.Show("Some text");
```

Do I need to start a new thread, and wait for it to finish?  I've never come across this problem before.

Comment: Try with `myForm.ShowDialog()`

Comment: um, you never called myForm.Close()

Comment: If you want your message box to appear over the window like an alert message, to what L.B said with MessageBox.ShowDialog(...)

Comment: @Benjamin He is confused that the MessageBox shows before he closes the form manuelly (red cross).

Comment: ah, well in that case, just open the message box in an OnClose event handler.

Comment: I think myForm.ShowDialog() should be adequate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [Form.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) instead. Form.Show shows a modeless window, whereas Form.ShowDialog shows a modal form, i.e., that the user has to close before continuing.

Comment: This of course assumes that the other form ought to be a modial form.  If it shouldn't the problem is still solvable in (several) other ways.

Comment: @Servy, yes, but I thought it was a reasonable assumption to make given the limited information; this is a common problem .Net beginners have.

Comment: @ShellShock Yes, it is a reasonable (and based on the comment, apparently appropriate) assumption .  My point is that you assumed the problem is more specific; the actual question is more general and has several other solutions.  The answer isn't *wrong*.  I'm simply saying that you don't *have* to make the form modal to get a message box to fire after the form closes, it's merely one option.

Answer (score 1):

Your example never actually closes `myForm`...only shows it. I would expect the code above to show `myForm` and then immediately show the `MessageBox`.

If you want `myForm` to close before showing the MessageBox, you'll need to call `myForm.Close()` at some point.

Comment: @Servy - Then the OP shouldn't expect the form to be closed before the MessageBox is shown. It's very possible that I didn't understand the question correctly as well since another solution seems to be the one the OP went with.

Comment: Yes, it is clearly incorrect for the OP to assume the form will be closed before the message box is shown.  One can assume the question is, "how do I get the message box to be shown after the form is closed".  For which there are a lot of possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that `myForm.Show();` starts the opening of a new window, however it is not a blocking call. It's not a dialog, it's a separate window, which runs on it's own.

If you want SomeForm to show as a Dialog (blocking window, waits for close to continue execution), then use `ShowDialog`. If you want to wait till the window is opened before you show the MessageBox, then add the MessageBox to the OnLoaded on the SomeForm claa.

Answer (score 1):

If it's important that the user not be able to interact with the main form while this other form is being shown then you can use `myForm.ShowDialog` instead of `Show`.  `ShowDialog` is a blocking function, so it won't return until the other form is closed.  `Show`, on the other hand, just shows the other form and then immediately returns without waiting for the form to be closed.

If it's intentional that the other form is not being shown modally, and you don't (or can't) make that change, then you can use events to show a message box when the other form is closed.

```
SomeForm myForm = new SomeForm();
myForm.FormClosed += (form, args) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("Some text");
};
myForm.Show();
```

This will add an event handler, which fires when the other form is closed, and executes the desired code at the appropriate time.